# Getting an error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, methods, nullpointerexception

What's wrong with my code? Basically, there is a menu and the user selects a number. After they choose "1", they can move on to the second method readData and select another number. If they choose "2", it works; however, if they choose "3" (the bestSeller method), I get the exception error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the method `Read_Data(...)` you are increasing the value of `c` (which you initialized with `0`) before you perform the operations. You must increase it at the end of the `while-loop`:

```
while ((text = readFile.readLine()) != null){
    // ... your stuff
    // ...
    c += 1; // At the end
}
```

**Edit:**

In the method `displayData(...)` your `for` *initialization* and *condition* values are wrong. Try changing this line

```
for (int i = 1; i <= dc; i++) {
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < dc; i++) {
```

**Edit 2:**

In `bestSeller(...)` method you are iterating `j` from `0` to `100` (array length). That causes an Exception, you may want to use the actual number of data read.

```
for (int j = 0; j < sortC - 1; j++) {
    for (int k = j + 1; k < sortC; k++) {
```

With this changes I get, for the **option 3 (bestSeller)**, the expected output (after modifying volume values in the `.txt`)

```
 POP        Beatles8        Let It Be       18.0
 POP        Beatles7        Let It Be       17.0
 POP        Beatles6        Let It Be       16.0
 POP        Beatles5        Let It Be       15.0
 POP        Beatles1        Let It Be       13.0
 POP        Beatles2        Let It Be       12.0
 POP        Beatles3        Let It Be       11.0
 POP        Beatles4        Let It Be       10.0
```

Comment: Okay, I moved the counter to the end and the first value is not null in the Best_Seller/bestSeller method any more. However, the readData method now doesn't work. I get another exception error.

Comment: See edit. In `displayData()` you are iterating one extra time.

Comment: That's not it, if I remove the = it only goes up to 7. I need the = to display 8 lines (which it does).

Comment: Sorry, see edit again, you are starting from `1` where you should start from `0`

Comment: If I start the loop at 0 it doesn't work at all - I get another exception error at line 175 - displayDsales = displayPrice[i] * displayVsales[i];

Comment: It works fine for me. I'm using the code you have posted (with all the modifications I mentioned). Make sure you have not modified anything else.

Comment: Oh, I moved the counter back to the top -- just moved it down and it does work. displayData works great (thank you), and the last value in bestSeller is not null anymore -- however I still get the exception error when trying to output the sorted arrays (error still at: if (sortVsales[k] > sortVsales[j]){

Comment: See edit again. I think you wanted to use the number of items you have read, not the length `100`.

Comment: Wow, thank you, that works -- but my teacher actually required the array lengths to be 100 because the assignment says that there are a maximum of 100 songs (even though the file is much less than that) I'm not sure why he made that a requirement?

Comment: If you are working with arrays, you must specify its length. To avoid this, use `ArrayList`(more flexible) but it may not be allowd for your assignment. Feel free to accept this answer if it was useful and solved your problem: [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Well if the output wouldn't work with the array length he specified I'm not sure why he specified it. He actually made me change it from 8 to 100. Thanks so much for your patience and your help!

Comment: It's OK what your teacher said, because when working with arrays, when you declare them you have to specify the `length`. It makes sense to put `100` as the length since it is the maximun number of songs.